# how toprevent page from scrolling down when anchor link inside of overflow-y is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an overflow-y div that is at the center of my page. I created some anchor link buttons that will scroll to a certain area within the overflow-y div. My problem is when a button is clicked the entire page scrolls to the top of that div in the center of my page. I just want the contents of my overflow-y div to scroll down without scrolling the entire page.

here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/badsyntax87/eprsnayf/28/

```
<div class="pageWrapper">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="serverNav">
        <a class="button" href="#server1">svr1</a>
        <a class="button" href="#server2">svr2</a>
        <a class="button" href="#server3">svr3</a>
        <a class="button" href="#server4">svr4</a>
        <a class="button" href="#server5">svr5</a>
    </div>
    <div id="servers">  
        <div id="server1">
            1
        </div>
        <div id="server2">
            2
        </div>
        <div id="server3">
            3
        </div>
        <div id="server4">
            4
        </div>
        <div id="server5">
            5
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate anchor offset and then set the [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/DOM/element.scrollTop) property of overflow-y div to that value.

```
function scrollToAnchor(elementId) {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    var anchor = document.getElementById(elementId);
    wrapper.scrollTop = anchor.offsetTop - wrapper.offsetTop;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yruac1pa/